# bind a list variable to text box

Tags: c#, textbox

i have a new question. i have a code to load a list from binary file, i think i did it right but i need to make each variable show in its own text box. this is the ting i cannot find out how to do. can anyone help me or point me to where i can find the information?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace test
 {

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ore
    {
        public float Titan;
        public float Eperton;
    }
    ore b1 = null;
    ore b2 = null;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b2 = new ore();
        b1 = new ore();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        float tempFloat;


        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            b1.Titan = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            b2.Eperton = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>();
        oreData.Add(b1);
        oreData.Add(b2);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, oreData);
        fs.Close();
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    List<ore> books = new List<ore>();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<ore> books = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        if (books.Count > 1)
        {
            textBox3.Text = books[0];//update the first text
            textBox4.Text = books[1];//update the second text
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the text boxes can be static there will only ever be 9 total and the list will be updates with 9 variables the text boxes need to read the binary file and display. for example text box 1 will show list variable 1 and so on

Comment: and to add the value the text box has to show is a float but i think i can parse that if i am correct

Comment: okay so how would i parse textBox3.Text = books[0]; i tried textBox3.Text = float.Parse(books[0]); but that did not work at all ?? i need the text boxes to display float and i get this error with current code above Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'test.Form1.ore' to 'string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Forms:

1- Define your List books at class level so you can use it in another methods if needed..

2-

```
public clas MyForm : Form
{
    List<ore> books = new List<ore>();//define at the class scope

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        books = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        if (books.Count > 1)
        {
            textBox3.Text = books[0];//update the first text
            textBox4.Text = books[1];//update the second text
        }
    } 
}
```

If you need  collection of list boxes to be added and removed whenever a book list changes then this is another story... write a comment or update your question...

Comment: oops ... i would need public class list<ore> ? im not sure how to define a list at class level

Comment: just define it at the upper scope of the method level i.e this is method and a list is defined at the method scope: `private void MyMethod() { List<int> myList = new List<int>();/*this is at method level and not available to other class methods*/}`  this would be at the class level:  `class MyForm : Form { List<int> myList = new List<int>(); /*this is at the class scope and valid to all methods*/ /*private void MyMethod(){}/*another methods*/*/}`

Comment: okay so just to make sure i have it figured out right i will have 2 different lists 1 for write and 1 for read

Comment: @doc: no you can use one list and perform the write and read from it.  `List<int> myList = new List<int>();` write: `myList.Add(25);` read: `int value = myList[0];//get the item at the index 0`

Comment: okay so how would i parse    textBox3.Text = books[0]; i tried    textBox3.Text = float.Parse(books[0]); but that did not work at all ?? i need the text boxes to display float and i get this error with current code above Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'test.Form1.ore' to 'string'

Comment: textBox.Text is accept a string type, so `textBox3.Text = books[0].ToString();` or `textBox3.Text = string.Fromat("Titan: {0}, Eperton: {1}",books[0].Titan, books[0].Eperton);`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use ListView control instead of a bunch of Textboxs. In the template of Listview, put Textbox control and bind it to your List object.

Alternatively, create Textbox control on the fly.

```
for(int i=1; i<=books.Count; i++)
{
  var textBoxCtrl = new TextBox()
  textBoxCtrl.ID = "TextBox"+i.toString();
  textBoxCtrl.Text = books[i];

  Page.Controls.Add(textBoxCtrl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.NET:
You can use the ASP.NET [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to create your form and then bind the dataset to the form and call the DataBind.

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="form1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: would that load the list from file and allow me to load only 1 variable from the list into the text box